# My father's family Schengen visa (including me) got refused, will this affect my ability to get a visa on my own?

Tags: visas, schengen

My family and I applied for a Schengen visa (our intention was tourism but it was a business visa) last June and it got refused because my dad applied for a visa at the French embassy (it was a business visa) and then traveled to Spain then to France.

After making that mistake, his Schengen visa gets refused every time. I would like to travel (tourism visa) with my friends, would there be any problem since he applied for a visa for the entire family and I was in it and our visas got refused together because of his mistake?

Comment: What's a “family Schengen visa”? Or a tourism or business visa for that matter? Are you certain the visa are refused merely because your fathered traveled through Spain? That would be odd.

Comment: What was the reason given for the refusal?

Comment: @Annoyed Sorry, the phrase *family Schengen visa* is the result of my edit.  Perhaps I misunderstood the OPs intent, you may wish to go through the revision history and edit the title.

Comment: In any case, it will be very difficult for anyone to predict how things might go. The Schengen agreement defines pretty detailed and transparent rules (compared to how things were before, at any rate) but there is still quite some latitude left to the consulates handling each application. What can be said is that they can and do refuse to issue visas if anything suggests that you might not stick to your stated plans (e.g. staying longer than allowed or working instead of doing tourism).

Answer (score 4):

As @Relaxed stated in a comment, it's hard to know exactly.  Your best bet is to apply, and if possible, write a letter pointing out the previous refusal and the reasons.

Contrary to popular opinion, many visa-processing officials are quite happy to help, and if any flags on your file are there, but can be logically and reasonably explained, they'll be happy.  As long as there's no logical reason to turn it down that they can see, odds should be that they'll approve it.

However, this is also life and you may get the one visa worker who is in a grumpy mood :)

TL;DR - write an accompanying letter explaining what happened in the past, and include copies of the rejection if you have it and perhaps even a letter from your father to accompany.  The more evidence and answers to any questions that they may have, the better it's likely to go.

Comment: Just another useful tidbit of information: There is a Schengen-wide database that is supposed to contain all previous visa refusals so that any consulate can find out about them. Being upfront about it therefore seems to be the best course of action.